# SQL 2012 Standard Edition (on Azure VM) + Bitlocker. Good or Bad idea?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, encryption

I will start this question with a few statements to negate any "Why" questions that are going to be asked.

- The Head of IT wants the data encrypted.
- Our profession is such that encrypted data is sensible.
- Enterprise Edition is an option, albeit a costly one.

We are looking at moving one of our user groups into Azure hosting (RDP, Files, Database, etal). Some members of the department are concerned that as Azure is a public cloud it is possible (although very improbable) that our data could be accessed by another party.

So at rest data encryption has been mooted; I would be happy to use SQLs native TDE, but that is an extra cost (and not a small one) so other options have been looked at.

The Systems Admin has put the idea of bitlocker forward; I know that SQL can be installed and run in a bitlocker encrypted drive. However is it a good idea; has anyone got any experience of using a enterprise level database on a bitlocker encrypted drive?

The sort of answers I am after will look at the performance, safety of both the data and the system; and perhaps suggest other options.

Comment: Regarding safety of TDE and BitLocker, see https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc278098.aspx.

Comment: @jamesakadamingo Did you go ahead with using BitLocker? If so has it worked OK?

Comment: We have trialled it in our dev environment and it seems to go well but that's with limited load. But we are still debating other options for live.